# Reorganize files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to move files written by a Hive job that look like this

```
/foo/0000_0
/foo/0000_1
/bar/0000_0
```

into a file structure that looks like this

```
/foo/prefix1/prefix2-0000_0
/foo/prefix1/prefix2-0000_1
/bar/prefix1/prefix2-0000_0
```

before migrating this out of the cluster (using s3distcp). I've been looking around hadoop fs but I can't find something that would let me do this. I don't want to rename file by file.

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to create the sub directory inside /foo. For this use following command

$hdfs dfs -mkdir /foo/prefix1

this will create a sub directory in /foo. if you want to create more subdirectory inside prefix1 use this same command recursively with updated path structure.In case you are using an older version of Hadoop (1.x) replace hdfs by hadoop.

now you can move files from /foo to /foo/prefix1 using the following command.Here newfilename can be any name you want to give to your file.

$hdfs dfs -mv /foo/filename /foo/prefix1/newfilename

Hope this answer your query

Comment: If all of your file have same prefix then you use approach by using * like mv filename* where filename is part of file name which is common to all and * will replace the part which is different . And if you want to move all the files from a folder To another folder use 

mv * /path/to/dest/folder/.                                  Refer this for more details http://askubuntu.com/questions/214560/how-to-move-multiple-files-at-once-to-a-specific-destination-directory